# Is there a way to know if transmission-daemon currently active?

Tags: shutdown, cron, transmission

I have a laptop that i use as a media station connected to my TV, occasionally i would fall a sleep and forget to shutdown the laptop and that is unwanted behavior. so i use crontabs to shutdown my laptop everyday at 7AM because i am sure that i am always either asleep or not at home then.

However sometimes i am actually downloading something using transmission-daemon and would prefer the laptop not to turn off at that time. Is there a way to check whether transmission daemon is downloading or not? like a file flag by transmission-daemon? i though about scanning the active ports used by transmission-daemon but i figured that there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The first one is with transmission not active, the second one is.

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ ps -ef | grep transmission | grep -v grep

rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ ps -ef | grep transmission | grep -v grep
rinzwind 10490     1 11 22:04 ?        00:00:00 transmission-gtk
```

> Is there a way to check whether transmission daemon is downloading or not?

Yes. There is an [API](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/2.9x/extras/rpc-spec.txt) and here is an [old script](https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2013/05/12/shut-down-when-complete-with-the-transmission-torrent-client/) from 2013 doing a shutdown for a MAC. Requires 1 change:

```
subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e','tell application "Finder" to shut down'])
```

needs to be something like this:

```
subprocess.call(['shutdown', '--now','turn off'])
```

It assumes you set up the web interface on port 9091

---

Pre req:

```
cd ~
virtualenv .transmission_env
source .transmission_env/bin/activate
pip install transmissionrpc
deactivate
```

and the script:

```
#!/Users/fots/.transmission_env/bin/python

import subprocess

import transmissionrpc
from transmissionrpc.error import TransmissionError


def main():
    all_done = True
    try:
        tc = transmissionrpc.Client('localhost', port=9091)
        for torrent in tc.get_torrents():
            if torrent.status == 'downloading':
                all_done = False
                break
        if all_done:
            subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e',
                             'tell application "Finder" to shut down'])
    except TransmissionError:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: shellcheck gave me an error tonight for `ps` piped to `grep`. It would recommend `pgrep transmission` instead. As a bonus this returns the PID which benefits the kill command as you don't need to use `tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2` to isolate PID. Still +1 for putting up with me :P